# Same collection of digits between two integers Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, numbers

I'm trying to check if two integers contain the same collection of digits.

```
equivalent(123, 321) // -> true
equivalent(413, 1453) // -> false
equivalent(2002, 2200) // -> true
equivalent(542, 545) // -> false
```

I've started off the function with:

```
function equivalent(a,b) {
    let stringA = a.toString().match(/[1-9]/g);
    let stringB = b.toString().match(/[1-9]/g);
}
```

I didn't know whether to use a hash map to map each occurrence of a digit and increment along, however I couldn't check if two objects are equal to each other.

---

Which method is most optimal(in terms of space/time complexity) and which method is most easily readable or both? Thanks.

---

Edit: Apologies for not elaborating a bit more on my question. I want to check if two integers contain the same digits and the same amount of those digits.

Comment: Would `.toString().length` be easier?

Comment: If I understand correct, apart from having the same length, the digits in them also should be the same, right?

Comment: If it is always going to be positive integers (i.e., just digits, no commas, decimal points, or negative signs), @j08691 's suggestion is the way to go.

Comment: Ooooh . . . I see what you're saying, @KapilKashyap . . . so "123" and "124" would be `false`, because the digits aren't the same.  Wow . . . confusing question.

Answer (score 2):

Use a simple loop and remove each character from the second string using [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and later check second string is empty(empty means both contains same amount of digits).

```js
console.log(
  equivalent(123, 321), // -> true
  equivalent(413, 1453), // -> false
  equivalent(2002, 2200) // -> true
);

function equivalent(a, b) {
  // convert into string
  a = a.toString();
  b = b.toString();
  // iterate over each character
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
  // replace each character from second string
    b = b.replace(a[i], '');
  // finally check second string is empty 
  return b == '';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could sort the figures and compare the joined strings.

```js
function equivalent(a, b) {
    return [...a.toString()].sort().join('') === [...b.toString()].sort().join('');
}

console.log(equivalent(123, 321));
console.log(equivalent(413, 1453));
console.log(equivalent(2002, 2200));
```

Approach with a hash table

```js
function equivalent(a, b) {
    var hash = Object.create(null);        
    [...a.toString()].forEach(a => hash[a] = (hash[a] || 0) + 1);
    [...b.toString()].forEach(b => hash[b] = (hash[b] || 0) - 1);
    return Object.keys(hash).every(k => !hash[k]);
}

console.log(equivalent(123, 321));
console.log(equivalent(413, 1453));
console.log(equivalent(2002, 2200));
```

Comment: @PranavCBalan, why do you think so?

Comment: the question contains `let`, so it's an ES6 question.

Comment: What is the `...` spread operator accounting for in your method? Thanks.

Comment: @kdizzle, it spreads a string into an array of single characters.

Answer (score 0):

Convert to string, split it, sort it, combine it and compare.

```js
function equivalent(a, b) {
  return a.toString().split("").sort().join("") === b.toString().split("").sort().join("");
}

console.log(equivalent(123, 321));
console.log(equivalent(413, 1453));
console.log(equivalent(2002, 2200));
```

Could add length check so the other processing does not need to take place.